# How to find the intersection between two MATLAB tall arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab

In common arrays the `intersection` function would have worked great, but for tall arrays this function has not been implemented yet. So is there an other way to find the common elements of these two?

Comment: From [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/functions-that-support-tall-arrays-a-z.html) documentation page, it looks like you will have to convert your tall arrays to either tables or timetables. You can apply intersect or ismember afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-loop to do the checks

```
n = 1e4;
m = 1e3; %Batchsize
a = tall(randi(n,n,1));
b = tall(randi(n,1,n));

idx = tall(false(n,1));
for ii = 1:n/m
    idx = idx | any(a==b(1,(ii-1)*m+1:ii*m),2);
end

inter = a(idx);
```

Where `m` controls how much of the array you can load into the memory at the time. The more the faster, but you will need to have enough memory for it.